# How can I determine whether or not a POS terminal violates requirements in the PCI DSS?

Tags: pci-dss

The business I work for uses an Equinox Optimum T4220 (hardware number 060001) in dial-out mode. I see two search results[1](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/popups/pts_device.php?appnum=4-60131) for "T4220" listed on the PCI SSC's website under Approved PIN Transaction Security (PTS) Devices[2](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/approved_companies_providers/approved_pin_transaction_security.php). These listings look similar to what we have, but I do not know if these results indicate our device is PTS approved for the following reasons:

- come from other manufacturers
- have a hardware number in the 0630xx and up (ours is 060001)

I would like to determine whether or not this terminal violates the PCI DSS's requirements on storing  cardholder data. I am concerned with requirements 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, and 3.4.

I am also concerned with cryptography and transmission as I have no way to detect violation of these rules either.

How can I determine whether or not a POS terminal negatively impacts this business' attempt to become compliant with the PCI DSS?

Comment: There is another product which I was unable to link to. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/popups/pts_device.php?appnum=4-60036

Answer (score 1):

I would say **no, these devices are not compliant.**

I did a search for "T4220", which found two listings on the PCI PTS site. Both are for hardware versions newer than what you have told us, and one of them is marked as EOL.

IANAQSA, but given that you cannot find the device you're interested in in the PTS, I would stop wondering about what other rules they may or may not be breaking and just replace them with something current.